# How to implicitly invoke a method when other methods are invoked?

Tags: scala

I have a class which defines a private maintenance method *synch*, which I want to always be invoked whenever any other method of the class is invoked. The classic way of doing this would of course be:

```
def method1 = {
    synch
    // ... do stuff
}

def method2 = {
    synch
    // ... do other stuff
}
```

However, is there any way to have this done implicitly, so that I do not have to invoke it explicitly like I do above?

**EDIT:**

If it is possible to do this, is it also possible to define if I want the *synch* method to be called **after** or **before** each other method?

Answer (score 3):

You could create your custom wrapper using [`def macros`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) and [`Dynamic`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Dynamic) like this:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

def applyDynamicImplementation(c: Context)(name: c.Expr[String])(args: c.Expr[Any]*) : c.Expr[Any] = {
  import c.universe._

  val nameStr = name match { case c.Expr(Literal(Constant(s: String))) => s }
  if (nameStr != "sync")
    c.Expr[Any](q"""{
      val res = ${c.prefix}.t.${newTermName(nameStr)}(..$args)
      ${c.prefix}.t.sync
      res
    }""")
  else
    c.Expr[Any](q"""${c.prefix}.t.sync""")
}

import scala.language.dynamics

class SyncWrapper[T <: { def sync(): Unit }](val t: T) extends Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: Any*): Any = macro applyDynamicImplementation
}
```

You'll have to use a [compiler plugin](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) for quasiquotes. If you want to call `sync` before method - just switch `val res = ...` and `${c.prefix}.t.sync` lines.

Usage:

```
class TestWithSync {
  def test(a: String, b: String) = {println("test"); a + b}
  def test2(s: String) = {println("test2"); s}
  def sync() = println("sync")
}

val w = new SyncWrapper(new TestWithSync)

scala> w.test("a", "b")
test
sync
res0: String = ab

scala> w.test2("s")
test2
sync
res1: String = s

scala> w.invalidTest("a", "b")
<console>:2: error: value invalidTest is not a member of TestWithSync
              w.invalidTest("a", "b")
                           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with bytecode rewriting, or with [macro annotations](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html). Both would be quite complicated. Some things to consider:

1. Do you also want this to happen to inherited methods?
2. If `synch` calls any other methods of this class, you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alexey! In my case, it would be sufficient if it work on a simple per-class basis, so there is no need to consider inherited method. Synch calls no other methods, it simply checks and updates the values of some private member variables.

Comment: @chrsva: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19977114/406435) for macro annotations example.

Answer (score 0):

**Implicit definitions are those that the compiler is allowed to insert into a program in order to fix any of its type errors.** For example, if x + y does not type check, then the compiler might change it to convert(x) + y, where convert is some available implicit conversion. If convert changes x into something that has a + method, then this change might fix a program so that it type checks and runs correctly. If convert really is just a simple conversion function, then leaving it out of the source code can be a clarification.

Basically `implicit` is used for conversion implicitly so i tried it using an example i think it will help you:

```
scala> class c{
     |  implicit def synch(x: String)=x.toInt+20
     | def f1(s: String):Int=s
     | }
```

what am i doing is :

i am implicitely conversing String to int and adding 20 to that number so for that i defined one method that is `synch` by using keyword `implicit` that will take `string` as an argument and after that convert value to `int` and adding `20` to it.

in next method if arugment is `string` and it return type is `Int` so it will implicitely call that synch method

```
scala> val aty=new c
aty: c = c@1f4da09

scala> aty.f1("50")
res10: Int = 70
```