# Insert one method invocation into many other methods

Tags: scala

I need to add a method to some other methods in the application. There are quite a lot of them. Is there any sensible way to do that except the straightforward one -- inserting the method call into each method manually?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19972102/406435). You could also use [macro annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19971700/406435) to rewrite methods automatically in compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19972102/406435) for implementation with `def macros`.

Implementation with [macro annotations](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html):

```
import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

def wrappedImpl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
  import c.universe._
  import scala.reflect.internal.Flags._

  object DefMods{
    def unapply(mods: Modifiers): Option[Modifiers] = {
      val fs = mods.flags.asInstanceOf[Long]
      if ((fs & DEFERRED) == 0 && (fs & STABLE) == 0) Some(mods)
      else None
    }
  }

  def wrap(t: Tree) = t match {
    case DefDef(DefMods(mods), name, tparams, vparams, tpt, body) if name != nme.CONSTRUCTOR =>
      DefDef(mods, name, tparams, vparams, tpt,
             q"""
               println("before")
               val res = $body
               println("after")
               res""")
    case x => x
  }

  def transform(t: Tree) = t match {
    case ClassDef(mods, name, tparams, Template(parents, self, methods)) =>
      ClassDef(mods, name, tparams, Template(parents, self, methods.map{wrap(_)}))
    case x => x
  }

  c.Expr[Any](Block(annottees.map(_.tree).map(transform(_)).toList, Literal(Constant(()))))
}

import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
class wrapped extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro wrappedImpl
}
```

You'll have to use a [compiler plugin](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) for quasiquotes.

Usage:

```
@wrapped class Test {
  def test() = println("test")
}

scala> new Test().test()
before
test
after
```